# ¿Cómo contar registros con Count?

Tags: mysql, select, count

tengo el siguiente inconveniente estoy realizando una consulta anidada con 3 tablas para devolver el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi SQL

```
SELECT
a.id as id_asesor,
a.nombres,
(SELECT COUNT(*) from REL_ASESOR_LOTE WHERE id_asesor) as total_lotes
FROM REL_ASESOR_LOTE as rel
INNER JOIN ASESORES as a ON id_asesor = rel.id_asesor
INNER JOIN LOTES as l ON l.id = rel.id_lote
GROUP BY rel.id_asesor
```

y este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que solo existe en la tabla `REL_ASESOR_LOTE` 2 registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en el resultado solo me muestra 1 nombre 2 veces, como puedo arreglar este error ?

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, lo que buscas es contar la cantidad de lotes por asesor. Esto podrías resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT a.id as id_asesor,
       a.nombres,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id)
       FROM REL_ASESOR_LOTE as rel
       INNER JOIN ASESORES as a 
             ON a.id = rel.id_asesor
       INNER JOIN LOTES as l 
             ON l.id = rel.id_lote
       GROUP BY a.id_asesor,
                a.nombres
```

Comentarios:

- El `mysql` es muy poco consistente con el estándar a la hora de manejar los `GROUP BY`, y eso es una fuente de problemas. Como buena práctica, toda columna en el `select` que no esté en una función de agregación debería repetirse en el `GROUP BY`
- Una vez conseguida la agrupación por asesor, simplemente hay que contar los lotes, lo hacemos con un `COUNT(DISTINCT l.id)` el  `DISTINCT` puede ser opcional, pero coo no conozco la relaciones, me asegura la suma de lotes distintos.